# Extract a string between two set of patterns in Python

Tags: python, regex, string

I am trying to extract a substring between two set of patterns using `re.search()`.

On the left, there can be either `0x` or `0X`, and on the right there can be either `U`,  , or `\n`. The result should not contain boundary patterns. For example, `0x1234U` should result in `1234`.

I tried with the following search pattern: `(0x|0X)(.*)(U| |\n)`, but it includes the left and right patterns in the result.

What would be the correct search pattern?

Comment: You may try regex: `^0[xX](.*?)U?$`

Comment: The search pattern at first glance looks okay (you presumably don't want so many capture groups)... how are you accessing the value... are you calling `.group(2)` on the match object where it's successful?

Comment: @JonClements I was printing the whole result. The `.group(2)` did the trick. Thank you!

Comment: You could use a single capture group https://regex101.com/r/W9pWyj/1 `0[xX](.*?)[U\s]`

Comment: @Thefourthbird I like your suggestion. I am not fluent with regex, but this pattern is easy to understand. Thanks!

Comment: @Marko I have added it as an answer with an explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use also use a single group using `.group(1)`

```
0[xX](.*?)[U\s]
```

The pattern matches:

- `0[xX]` Match either `0x` or `0X`
- `(.*?)` Capture in **group 1** matching any character except a newline, as least as possible
- `[U\s]` Match either `U` or a whitespace characters (which could also match a newline)

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/W9pWyj/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/4K88vD)

```
import re

s = r"0x1234U"
pattern = r"0[xX](.*?)[U\s]"

m = re.search(pattern, s)
if m:
    print(m.group(1))
```

Output

```
1234
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a combination of lookbehind and lookahead with a non-greedy match pattern in between:

```
import re
   
pattern = r"(?<=0[xX])(.*?)(?=[U\s\n])"

re.findall(pattern,"---0x1234U...0X456a ")

['1234', '456a']
```